# Notepad++ How can I replace nothing with something?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to use the batch "Find in Files" to replace multiple files.  The problem is I can't "Replace All" because the files are completely empty.

What do I put in "Find what:" when the file is completely empty so that I can replace it with content?

Comment: Is there not something to just set text? If nothing else, try `.*`, though that will match everything if there is something there.

Comment: So basically you want to create new files with old names? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Boost RegEx documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) referenced via [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/712151/making-notepads-match-the-end-of-the-file-instead-of-the-end-of-the-line):

```
\A\Z
```

Should match an empty buffer. I've tested this out on my local install with the buffer after selecting File/New.

Note: Please test on a copy of your directory just in case everything blows up!

Note2: There seems to be a bug in v7.2.2 at least; Search once for `\A\Z` on a non-empty file and it matches, search again and it fails, then once again succeeds. This could be an underlying Boost bug, perhaps? On a non-empty file "Find Next" then "Replace" makes one replacement, "Replace All" makes none.

Note3: Reported as [bug on GitHub](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2671).